# Show there exist bijective functions.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a set with $3$ elements. Show that there exist bijective functions

$f : X ->X$ and $g : X ->X$, such that $f∘g≠g∘f$

I'm pretty confused on where to start exactly. I need to prove the composites of f and g are not equal. But what arbitrary values do I give the functions f and g? They need to be bijective and have 3 elements to them as stated in the question.

Any help on this one is appreciated.

Comment: All you need is a single example.  Just list a few bijections and look at their compositions.

Answer (score 1):

Name the $3$ elements as $0,1,2$.

Let $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=0$, and $f(2)=2$.

Let $g(0)=0$, $g(1)=2$, and $g(2)=1$.

Comment: Oh okay alright, I computed all of those composites and they do not equal. But just for clarification, what makes those functions bijective here?

I understand that a function g: B->A is bijective if and only if, $g∘f=T_A$ and $f∘g=I_B$

Comment: @Bugcatcher123 what is the definition of bijective?

Comment: Sorry I added the definition I understand at the end (I accidentally pressed enter to drop a line before I can write my understanding to it, but it posted my response immediately).

Comment: That isn't how you define bijection.

Comment: Hmm well I'm thinking it has to due with how all the functions or elements pair perfectly with each other. That would mean that the two "sets" of functions are bijective I believe.